# Math.min.apply(Math,Array) return NaN when Array.length = 100

Tags: javascript, arrays, min, mathjax

when using the Math.min.apply and the Array.length is 10 is ok

```
getAllIndexes(arr, val) {
var indexes = [], i = -1;
while ((i = arr.indexOf(val, i+1)) != -1){
    indexes.push(i);
}
return indexes;
}

 arrayMinIndex(array) {
return this.getAllIndexes(array, Math.min.apply(Math,array));
}
```

[image]

but when the Arrays is more big in this case length = 100, the val is NaN,

[image]

UPDATE!!!!

if I change the index name of 00,01,02,03 ... 99 to 0,1,2,3,4 ... 99 its work

[image]

in this part  I created the Array dynamically, the index name is a String.
[image]

but for what the index name is problem to the MAth.min?

Comment: please create a working example

Comment: Your array must hold a non numeric value somewhere.

Comment: he revised the whole array and they are all numbers,

Comment: Are you sure you don't have an empty slot?

Comment: I'm sorry, I checked it, I asking

Comment: or only `Math.min.apply(Math, Array.from({length:125897}, (_, i) => - i))` 125897 elements if you're running Chrum

Comment: Yep I checked and all slot have one numerical value

Comment: I change the Array index in the firts case I put 00,01,02,03....99 and return NaN but if I put in the index 0,1,2,3 .... 99 its work

Comment: but I dont know for what :(

Comment: "if I change the index name" ... again, I ask ... *show how the array is created* - I swear I beleive you are doing something like `array['01'] = 13` - which would mean index 1 is empty - because `array['01']` is not the same thing as `array[1]` - so, for the last time ... *show how the array is created*

Comment: show the update,

Comment: `the index name is a String` - see my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems when you are creating the array, you are creating keys like '01', '02' etc

these are different to index 1 and 2

See the following

```js
const array1 = new Array();
const array2 = new Array();
const array3 = new Array();
array1[0] = 1;
array2['00'] = 2
array3[0] = 3
array3['00'] = 4

console.log(JSON.stringify(array1), typeof array1[0]);
console.log(JSON.stringify(array2), typeof array2[0]);
console.log(JSON.stringify(array3), typeof array3[0]);
```

see how array2[0] is `undefined` ... now if you do

```js
const array = new Array();
array['00'] = 10;
array['01'] = 9;
array['02'] = 8;
array['03'] = 7;
array['04'] = 6;
array['05'] = 5;
array['06'] = 4;
array['07'] = 3;
array['08'] = 2;
array['09'] = 1;
array['10'] = 100;
console.log(array);
```

look at all those `undefined` before index 10

that's why Math.min results in `NaN`

Comment: Wow you're right, I never thought that was possible, now I have all night to be able to solve that XD Thanks so much

Comment: an array is an object, so it can have any properties added to it ... and `'01'` is not the same as `'1'` ... but in an array, `'1'` is treated as an actual index, whereas `'01'` is not

Comment: then I need to remove the 01 and put 1?

Comment: I can't tell where the array is being populated ... but, if the key value is `'01'` then you could `parseInt(v, 10)` - if the variable holding `01` is named `v` .... again, I can't see where in your code the array is being populated, so, you can figure it out yourself

Comment: yep, Thanks so much :D

Answer (score 0):

Your first filter non-numeric values looks Your contain array non-numeric value.

```js
var filteredArr = arr.filter(function (item) {
  return !isNaN(item);
});
```

For min in the array, you should use

```js
Math.min.apply(Math,array.filter(n => !isNaN(n)))
```

Comment: `parseInt` do they HAVE to be integers?

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong I have updated my code using your code help. Thanks @JaromandaX